# Encoding Output and Input in .NET Core Console apps

Tags: c#, .net-core, character-encoding

I've got a CSV file that I need to parse, display and request input about.

So I created a project in .net core (2.2). It works as expected excepts for one thing.

The app reads the CSV (using CsvHelper, with default UTF8 settings) and fills my objects with it. There is a particular field that I need to split and the separators in this field have been entered by hands by users over the years. I've made a file with a list of known separators and I've made it so that when I run my console app, whenever it encounters a value that it cannot split using a known separator, it displays the value and asks which separator it is. So I just copy / paste the separator from the value and my app adds it to the list of known separators.

That works for most case, but I found that for some strange strings, it doesn't.

From the CSV (copy/paste)

```
<p>  _  _  _  _</p>
```

From the Console Output (copy/paste)

```
<p>  _  _  _  _</p>
```

From the Console's ReadLine()

```
<p>  _  _  _  _</p>
```

They all look similar enough, but if I run string.Contains() using the one copy/pasted from the CSV, it returns true, but the one from the Console doesn't.
I've tried setting the console's encoding to UTF8, Unicode, nothing helps

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

I've made a minimalist repro :

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var productList = ReadProductCsv();
            Console.WriteLine($"Description: {productList[0].Description}");
            Console.WriteLine("Copy the separator and paste it : " + Environment.NewLine);
            var separator = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine( $"Description Contains the separator : {productList[0].Description.Contains(separator)}");
        }

        private static List<Product> ReadProductCsv()
        {
            List<Product> products;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader("Example.csv"))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                products = csv.GetRecords<Product>().ToList();
            }
            return products;
        }
    }
```

Outputs:

```
Description: Some Description <p>  _  _  _  _</p> Some Other Description
Copy the separator and paste it :

<p>  _  _  _  _</p>

Description Contains the separator : False
```

Even looking at this page's code with Chrome dev tools, i can see that the Console ReadLine version is different :

[image]

Repro source code (including a problematic CSV file) : 
http://www.filedropper.com/reproconsolestringcompare

Any idea how I could get proper Copy-Paste working using Console.ReadLine() ?

I've got about 15 thousand lines to deal with, so I figured an interactive console app that asks for human input when it needs it was gonna do the trick.

Comment: The PrettyPrint is different becase in the first 2 cases you have `&nbsp;&nbsp;` forced spaces, while in the last case you have 2 char `32` (standard white space, shown once in the HTML). The underscore is always char `95`. Maybe, use `Console.ReadKey();` and instruct to input the separator char with the keyboard. But, since this separator is a symbol and is recurring an exact number of times, you could code it out, maybe asking a User `"Did I got it right? (Y/N)"`. If `N`, then let a User input it. It depends on how many times in *15 thousand lines* this happens.

Comment: I don't know why you have to do all this, but you could/should get that CSV, parse it once yourself, convert all separators (different separators were allowed, here?) to a single one and re-pack.

Comment: @Jimi, as mentioned, the separators were entered by the users (many of them) over many years. So far my file with know separators has over 100 entries. Sometimes it's underscores, sometimes it's dashes, sometimes it's html tags with weird content... I suspect there is around a thousand different separators, which is why a made an interactive console app, so that I can enter them as i see them for entries that do not separate using previously known ones.

Comment: Here's an example of some separators:
<p>- - - -</p>, <p>----</p>, <p> ----</p>, <p>&nbsp; _ &nbsp;_ &nbsp;_ &nbsp;_, <p>___</p>, <br />-  -  -  -<br />, <br />- - - -<br />, <p><span class=""item-description__content"">- - - - </span></p>, <p>- - - - </p>, <p class="p1">- - - -</p>, <p>- - - - - - -</p>, <p class="p3"><span class="s2"><span class="Apple-converted-space">- - - -<br /></span></span></p>

Comment: And just so we're clear, the csv does parse. It's just that this column/field was used to store two product descriptions (one in french, one in english) in the past, the ecom platform used now supports many language. That's why I have to split them and put them into actual different columns/fields,

Comment: And another thing, i know my examples are all html based, but some values for this column/field of the csv file are not html, just plain text and they have variations too. Hell, i even got one value where the separator was "*****************" and some just have a carriage return.

At this point, i'm guessing i should switch to a GUI app and go by Selection/Cursor position to extract the separator using string.Substring() and replace it with a single separator. Like you suggested in the second comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a WinForm app and used selected text start index + it's length to extract from the original string, instead of using a console app with copy/pasted text or even the selected text itself.
That way I was able to get the separators.